# Gulp not creating CSS file in destination

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, gulp-watch

I am trying to set the Gulp tasks for styles with postcss, CSS modules etc., but for now only the watch task for the main HTML file is working, and it is not even creating the main CSS file **nor the temp folder** so I get the error in the console that it can not find the styles.css. It's driving me crazy for days but just cannot get to the bottom of it. Here is my file structure, pretty basic:

```
application -> views -> index.html

public -> gulp -> tasks -> styles.js, watch.js
       -> styles (styles.css inside, base and modules for CSS subfolders)
```

And here are the styles and watch tasks:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        notify: false,
        server: {
            baseDir: "../application/views"
        }
    });

    watch('../application/views/index.html', function(){
        browserSync.reload();
    });

    watch('../application/public/styles/**/*.css', function(){
        gulp.start('cssInject');
    });
});

gulp.task('cssInject', ['styles'], function(){
    return gulp.src('../application/temp/styles')
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Styles:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    nested = require('postcss-nested'),
    cssImport = require('postcss-import'),
    mixins = require('postcss-mixins'),
    hexrgba = require('postcss-hexrgba');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return gulp.src('../application/public/styles/styles.css')
        .pipe(postcss([cssImport, mixins, cssvars, nested, hexrgba, autoprefixer]))
        .on('error', function(errorInfo){
            console.log(errorInfo.toString());
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../application/temp/styles'));
});
```

If someone can give a piece of advice I would be really grateful.

Comment: No effect, temp folder is not even created :/

Comment: are you sure about the src path??? ../application/public/styles/styles.css and alos of styles name? ..whatif you try with ../application/public/**/*.css

Comment: Where is your gulpfile.js?  The src's are relative to its location.